# django ignore changed field in formset

Tags: python, django, django-forms, inline-formset

I have the following models:

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    fields...

class Ingredient(models.Model):
    fields...

class UsesIngredient(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe)
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient)
    amount = models.FloatField()
    group = models.CharField()
```

I have a view which lets the user add any number of 'UsesIngredient' models for a certain recipe through a dynamic formset. The group attribute is automatically filled in an hidden from the user.

The problem is that when the users adds a new form in the formset, but doesn't fill in any of the fields, I don't want that form saved. However, django still tries to save the form because the 'group' attribute has 'changed' (because it has been automatically filled in when the extra form was created).

Is there any way to get around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I still didn't feel completely comfortable with Tim Edgar's solution, so I kept looking. I guess I found what I was looking for.
The 'Form' class, has two undocumented methods that are of use in this case: 'has_changed()' and '_get_changed_data'.

During ModelFormSet validation, every form checks 'has_changed()'. If the form did not changed, validation is skipped and a correct form is assumed.
Likewise, during ModelFormSet saving, the save_new_objects checks every form to see if it has changed. If it didn't change, the form isn't saved.

So my solution was to override the has_changed() method to return False if only the 'group' attribute has changed, and all other fields are empty. This is my implementation:

```
class UsesIngredientForm(forms.ModelForm):    
    class Meta:
        model = UsesIngredient

    def has_changed(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._get_changed_data(*args, **kwargs)
        # If group is in changed_data, but no other fields are filled in, remove group so
        # the form will not be validated or saved
        if 'group' in self._changed_data and len(self._changed_data) == 1:
            contains_data = False
            for name in ['ingredient', 'amount', 'unit']:
                field = self.fields[name]
                prefixed_name = self.add_prefix(name)
                data_value = field.widget.value_from_datadict(self.data, self.files, prefixed_name)
                if data_value:
                    contains_data = True
                    break
            if not contains_data:
                self._changed_data.remove('group')
        return bool(self._changed_data)
```

Hope this helps anybody in the future!

EDIT:
I edited this answer to reflect Tim Edgars comment.
I realize that this implementation still uses 'private' methods, but I haven't found a cleaner implementation using just the publicly documented methods. But then maybe that is just my own incompetence :).

Comment: It's not a good practice to overwrite private/undocumented methods.  Typically in a languages like Python that don't have proper class visibility, you denote private methods with an underscore `_private_method`.  Django can change the functionality of undocumented methods at any time, where as they'll try to maintain the functionality of public methods.

Comment: Well, it's also possible to overwrite the 'has_changed()' method, which is public. The same result can be achieved by doing that, and I agree that it is better practice, so I will edit my answer.

Comment: As of django 5 (and possibly before, I haven't checked), the former private
method `_get_changed_data` is replaced by a public and documented method 
`changed_data`. Docs reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.changed_data

Answer (score 0):

You could try making all your fields to require a value by setting `blank=False`.  See more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.blank).  It should require validation that the values that you care about are not left blank.

If that doesn't work, you can try creating your own custom `save` method that does the validation that you care about.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
   # Do your checks on the properties such as self.group, self.amount, etc
   # If it is fine then call
   super(UsesIngredient, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: The thing is, I want to allow the user to all the fields that he can see blank (and if he does, I just want django to ignore that form)...

Comment: Then overwrite the save method on your form as mentioned in answer.  Just don't call super().save if the properties aren't what you want.

Comment: Ok, this isn't really clear from my question, but the form gets validated before the save() method is called. And because the required fields aren't filled in, this validation fails.

I just doesn't feel right to overwrite both the clean() and the save() methods for this functionality...

Comment: You want it to do something different from the default behavior.  Outside restructuring how you are doing your formsets, you'll want to overwrite the default behavior to match what you want.  There really isn't anything wrong with creating a custom save or clean function that matches your desired functionality.

Comment: Ok, I'll accept your answer then. I was just under the impression that django had some built-in option to define a form field as ignorable or something...
Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since the question was asked and answered, django changed to include a public
and documented method `changed_data`, which can be helpful for implementing a
similar solution to what Gargamel suggested.

For example:

```
class UsesIngredientForm(forms.ModelForm):    
    class Meta:
        model = UsesIngredient

    def has_changed(self):
        """
        Checks if only the "group" field has changed data. If so, returns `False`,
        indicating no data of relevance has changed. This avoids triggering validation
        if only the "group" value changed from its initial state. 
        """
        changed_data = self.changed_data

        if len(changed_data) == 1 and changed_data[0] == "group":
            return False
        
        return super().has_changed()
```

The `changed_data` attribute is documented here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.changed_data

> The changed_data attribute returns a list of the names of the fields whose values in the form’s bound data (usually request.POST) differ from what was provided in initial. It returns an empty list if no data differs.